# What influences the visibility of the layer selection in the view port header?

Tags: interface

For some reason the layer selection and the *Lock to Scene* button disappeared in *3D View / Object Mode*. I can't find an option to toggle the visibility.

<sup>As it is supposed to look like</sup>
[image]

<sup>How it currently looks like</sup>

[image]

File / New restores the visibility therefore it must be a setting within the .blend file.
How can the layer selection be restored?

Comment: Are you by any chance in Local View Mode? (Numpad /)

Comment: @user2859 Oh this could be, I can't check this for the next 8-9 hours. If so "(local)" should be appended to the viewport like Top Ortho (local)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### **Local and Global View**

From the [Blender wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Navigating/3D_View):

> You can toggle between Local and Global view by selecting the option
>   from the View Menu or using the shortcut <kbd>NumPad /</kbd>. Local view isolates
>   the selected object or objects, so that they are the only ones visible
>   in the viewport. This is useful for working on objects that are
>   obscured by other ones, or have heavy geometry. Press <kbd>NumPad /</kbd> to
>   return to Global View.

As [user2859](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/2859/user2859) pointed out, when you are in Local View, the Layers buttons are not visible, but will return when you go back to Global view.

Comment: IIRC, they also go away in edit mode, don't they?

Comment: Yes Matt, they do go away in Edit mode.